# how to update multiple fields via

Tags: python, django, bulk-create

how to update multiple fields via

```
Model.objects.bulk_create(list)
```

I try it

```
Model.objects.bulk_create(list).update(startD=startD, endD=endD)
```

but error show 'list' object has no attribute 'update'

Comment: Can you please mention why you are using bulk_create() in the code segment? Do you want to add startD and endD while the bulk create operation is executing?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
Model.objects.update(anythings)
```

this code will update all of the table from this model

but if you want to update one of the data table of this model try this code:

```
Model.objects.filter(limit_the_data_table).update(anythings)
```